# Android test loading file from res/raw

Tags: android

I want to test that a file is loaded from res/raw but can't seem to get it working.

The class I'm testing is:

```
public class SomeService extends ContextWrapper {

    public SomeService(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public BufferedReader loadSuperFile() {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.superFile);
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    }
}
```

With the test class being:

```
@Test
public void aTest() {
    SomeService someService = new SomeService(new MainActivity().getApplicationContext());
    BufferedReader br = someService.loadSuperFile();
}
```

But I get a RuntimeException: Method getApplicationContext in android.content.ContextWrapper not mocked.

I suspect it's the context but just can't find the magic formula.

Comment: not sure. does it help any to stop getting the Context object from MainActivity.getApplicationContext() and instead get it from InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext() ?

Comment: I would highly recommend trying Robolectric for this sort of test.  It eliminates the need for mocking context.